# Wilson's theorem could be simplified?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, primality-test

I know that Wilson's theorem states that a number n is prime iff

```
   (n - 1)! congruent to -1 (mod n)
```

However, since

```
   (n - 1) congruent to -1 (mod n)
```

Why isn't the theorem simplified to the following condition?

```
  (n - 2)! congruent to 1 (mod n)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed true that $n\ge 2$ is prime if and only if $(n-2)!\equiv 1\pmod n$.

"*Why isn't the theorem simplified to this condition?*": why should it?  It looks basically the same to me.

Comment: My point is that my simplification has already factored away n - 1 mod n from the equation (since that is always the result of this step). And to me it looks more natural to have the positive modulo result instead of having -1 mod n.

Comment: I think you may be right that there is a sense in which the $n-2$ version is simpler.  But it's not exactly that, because you can factor away $-1$ _again_ to get the other version.

Comment: The equation is defined for n >= 2. Factoring away -1 again would seemingly assume that n >= 3.

Comment: @MånsNilsson No. The statement "$n\ge 2$ is prime if and only if $(n-1)!\equiv -1\pmod n$" is true.

Comment: @Sassatelli: I was referring to my version to start with in that comment.