# Is there a pattern in the sequence $l_1,l_2,l_3,\ldots$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

Wilson's theorem asserts the following statement: $$(n-1)!\equiv -1\pmod n\Leftrightarrow n\text{ is prime.}\tag1$$ This means that $$\begin{align} n&{ \ \mid} \ \ (n-1)!+1 \\ \Leftrightarrow n&{ \ \mid} \ \ (n-1)!+1-n \\
 &=(n-1)!-(n-1) \\ &= (n-1)\big((n-2)!-1\big) \\ \therefore n&{ \ \mid} \ \ (n-2)!-1 \\ \Leftrightarrow (n-2)!&\equiv 1\pmod n.\tag2\end{align}$$ Or, in the congruence, I could add $n$ to the right hand side, and then divide both sides by $n-1$, yeilding the same result.

I then asked myself, *why wouldn't Wilson's theorem assert that* $$(n-2)!\equiv 1\pmod n\Leftrightarrow n\text{ is prime,}$$ *as opposed to $(1)$*? It is more useful because $(n-2)! < (n-1)!$, so we can test this theorem with more primes without the factorial becoming too large as fast in $(1)$, and it is still just as interesting. However, I went [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2309783/wilsons-theorem-could-be-simplified) and found that it really is not that necessary to simplify the theorem.

Now, I have been trying to find some similar result for $(n-3)!$, and I found that $$(n-3)!\equiv \frac{n-1}{2}\pmod n\Leftrightarrow n\text{ is prime $> 2$.}$$

> > **Main Question:** If for some $k\in\mathbb{Z^+}$ and remainder $l_k\in\mathbb{Z}$, $$(n-k)!\equiv l_k\pmod n,\tag{$n$ is prime}$$ is there a pattern in the sequence $l_1, l_2, l_3,\ldots$?
> >
> > Do there exist similar congruences for $(n-k)!$ such that $k > 3$?

Thank you in advance.

---

This post was inspired by [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2743936/a-combinatorial-proof-of-wilsons-theorem-proof-verification).

Comment: Don't abuse notation. It is not true tbat $(n-1)!+1=(n-1)!-(n-1).$

Comment: $(n-1)!\equiv (-1)\cdot (n-2)!\pmod{n}$ all the time, so there really isn't a cost to computing $(n-1)!.$ It's just a multiplication of $-1\pmod{n}.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I know that. But it's just because of divisibility that we can cancel the $n$. If $n\mid a + n$ then of course $n\mid a$. That doesn't mean $a = a + n$. I know what u mean though

Comment: It is a matter of taste whether residue $1$ is more useful than residue $-1$. Calculating $(n-2)!$ modulo $n$ is as difficult as calculating $(n-1)!$ modulo $n$ , so we still cannot find large primes with this criterion. And even if we calculate $(n-100)!$ modulo $n$ for very large $n$, it won't make a significant diffference in complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that since $n$ is prime, we can define the following:
$$y \equiv \frac{a}{x} \pmod{m} \iff n  \mid  xy-a \space (x,y,a\neq 0) $$

We can use the same properties of congruence such as adding, subtracting, multiplying and dividing by relatively prime constants.

Now, to find $(n-2)! \pmod{n} \space$, we basically need to find $\frac{1}{n-1} \pmod{n}$. We can instead write $n-1 \pmod{n}$ as $-1 \pmod{n}$. Thus, we have $\frac{1}{-1} \equiv -1 \pmod{n} $ which gives you that $(n-2)! \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$ using Wilson's Theorem.

The same idea goes on for $(n-k)!$. We are to evaluate $\frac{1}{-k} \pmod{n}$. For $k=1$, we trivially get $-1$. For $k=2$, considering $n$ as an odd prime, we know that $2 \mid n+1$. Thus, $\frac{n+1}{2}$ is an integer from  which we can derive $(n-3)! \pmod{n}$.

Unfortunately, this process can no longer continue. A prime can be any value modulo another odd prime less than it except $0$. Thus, we cannot detect any pattern.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I had already figured this out. ‘Tis why I didn’t put a bounty on it, but I forgot to actually answer my own question.... however, your answer is nearly exactly the same as was my own, so I am gonna give you a tick. I’ll also give you a $+100$ bounty just because. Congratulations! $(+1)$ $\color{green}{\checkmark}$

Comment: Thank you. I'm glad I could be helpful.

Comment: It only took $5$ months, hahah :P (well, a "formal" answer, that is)

Comment: If you are interested in understanding factorials modulo primes, there is a question I have asked regarding them. Any progress or insight would be appreciated. The question is: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2651733/stronger-versions-of-wilsons-theorem

Comment: Thanks. I will check it out :)

Comment: I looked at it, and 'tis beyond my level, really. I must let you know, I am quite young, and as much as I love maths (and as much as I might have a similar dream to you, after looking at your bio), I do not know of any such theorems or ways that I can help you with your question. I have tried looking at other posts relating to Wilson's Theorem; went on Wikipedia; also went on Wolfram; but don't know how to provide an insightful answer, or even the least bit sufficient. Sorry about that, but nice work nonetheless! :)

Comment: No problem. It is quite hard.

Comment: Glad you understand. In fact, I am currently working on something else right now. Since you do dream of being a number theorist, you might be interested. It concerns the Fibonacci numbers and square numbers, and sort of bonds them together in a way... or well, it's a conjecture, really. Want to have a discussion about it in chat? I don't mind if you can't or don't wish to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83771/discussion-between-haran-and-user477343).